# How Can I Schedule Automatic Download Morning Edition Podcast?

Tags: podcast, downloaders

I would like to automatically download the Morning Edition podcast every day. I do not own any apple products. I downloaded and installed flareget, but cannot figure out how to make it do this.  I am not locked into that tool.  I am a long time Firefox user, but am currently test driving Chrome.

The URL for the program is:  http://www.npr.org/programs/morning-edition/

The RSS address is: http://www.npr.org/rss/rss.php?id=3

The trouble is that the RSS includes a link to a web page for the individual story instead of a link to the mp3.

```
<rss xmlns:npr="http://www.npr.org/rss/" xmlns:nprml="http://api.npr.org/nprml" xmlns:itunes="http://www.itunes.com/dtds/podcast-1.0.dtd" xmlns:content="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/content/" xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" version="2.0">
<channel>
<title>
    Morning Edition : NPR
</title>
<link>
    http://www.npr.org/templates/story/story.php?storyId=3
</link>
<description>
    Morning Edition gives its audience news, analysis, commentary, and coverage of arts and sports. Stories are told through conversation as well as full reports. It's up-to-the-minute news that prepares listeners for the day ahead.
</description>
<language>en</language>
<copyright>Copyright 2015 NPR - For Personal Use Only</copyright>
<generator>NPR API RSS Generator 0.94</generator>
<lastBuildDate>Fri, 06 Nov 2015 12:45:00 -0500</lastBuildDate>
<image>
    <url>http://media.npr.org/images/podcasts/primary/npr_generic_image_300.jpg?s=200</url>
    <title>Morning Edition</title>
    <link>http://www.npr.org/templates/story/story.php?storyId=3</link>
</image>
<item>
    <title>Russian Airliner Crash Update</title>
    <description>
        The latest information on the Russian airliner that crashed in Egypt. All 224 people on board were killed.
    </description>
    <pubDate>Fri, 06 Nov 2015 12:45:00 -0500</pubDate>
    <link>
        http://www.npr.org/2015/11/06/455019224/russian-airliner-crash-update?utm_medium=RSS&utm_campaign=morningedition
    </link>
    <guid>
        http://www.npr.org/2015/11/06/455019224/russian-airliner-crash-update?utm_medium=RSS&utm_campaign=morningedition
    </guid>
    <content:encoded>
        <![CDATA[
        <p>The latest information on the Russian airliner that crashed in Egypt. All 224 people on board were killed.</p>
        ]]>
    </content:encoded>
    <dc:creator>Corey Flintoff</dc:creator>
</item>
...
```

When I open `http://www.npr.org/2015/11/06/455019224/russian-airliner-crash-update?utm_medium=RSS&utm_campaign=morningedition`
 in my browser, there is a link on the page to the mp3 file for the story:
`http://pd.npr.org/anon.npr-mp3/npr/me/2015/11/20151106_me_egypt_plane_crash_probe_russia.mp3?dl=1`

I can see that there is an easily identifiable pattern that I could use, but cannot figure out what tools to use or how to make them do what I want.

Every story's audio file starts with:

```
http://pd.npr.org/anon.npr-mp3/npr/me/
```

then add a folder for the year

```
http://pd.npr.org/anon.npr-mp3/npr/me/2015
```

and one for the month

```
http://pd.npr.org/anon.npr-mp3/npr/me/2015/11
```

all of the mp3's for today's show are

```
yyyymmdd_me*.mp3
```

The trailing `?dl=1` does not seem to be necessary.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to write a web robot to navigate the site until it finds the .mp3 URL(s) you want to download and then download exactly those URL(s).

For `perl`, the obvious solution is to use the [libwww-perl](http://search.cpan.org/dist/libwww-perl/) package (aka `LWP`).

For `python`, I'll recommend the [mechanize](http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/) or [scrapy](http://scrapy.org/) python libraries.

Both of these python libs are packaged for Debian and Ubuntu as `python-mechanize` and `python-scrapy`, so install the packages (and don't follow the `pip install` or whatever instructions on the web sites)

There are similar libraries for other languages.

Comment: Sigh... I am so not a programmer.  I have waaay down on my to do list to start learning Genie.  This will have to go below that for now.